# Can Sitecore 9.1 be configured to have LB from application perspective?

Tags: sitecore-client, configuration, scaling

Does Sitecore 9.1 have any option to have internal Load balance ?

As we have two CD, can sitecore internally manage the Load balancing rather than server/LB doing the Load balance.

Thanks for you kind replies.

Regards,

Avinash

Comment: No. Sitecore doesn't have internal LB

Comment: if your Sitecore is setup Azure, you can increase the no of instances in your app service plan based on rules like memory usage, cpu usage percentages, etc

Comment: Sitecore xp1 scaled architecture with each server having one process and its on-Premise @MaheshRaghupathi